# How to set the background not move in differents resolutions?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the menu of my store. If you enter my webpage, [http://masluzz.panamerik.net/](http://masluzz.panamerik.net) you can see the menu on the top is colored in gray and orange, but when I change the resolution of the page the background menu moves to the right side. I don't know how I can view on all resolutions without moving the background. Here is the css thanks!

```
#sticky {
padding: 0.0ex;
width: 100%;
clear: both;
color: #transparent;
font-size: 2em;
border-radius: 0.0ex;
background: url(/img/layout/menu.png) 38.5% 0% repeat-y;
border-radius: 0.0ex;
position: relative;
top: -3px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the orange to go all the way across the menu? Instead of a background-image you could just use CSS.

```
background: #FE6900;
```

If you only want half of the menu or w\e to be that color, you could add a class like "orange-bg" to the li's that you want.

Comment: It  doesnt work, i need move the color orange certain porcentaje to the right, but when i see it in other resolutions the orange color invade more

Answer (score 0):

try change the position to absolute.

```
position: absolute;
```

Comment: Not work i want this, i add the preview image, graphic explain.
http://oi60.tinypic.com/2l5ezd.jpg